# Is it reasonable approach when C++ function does not 'move from' rvalue reference argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Suppose the `class Object` satisfies the requirements of *MoveConstructible* and *MoveAssignable*, but not the requirements of either *CopyConstructible* or *CopyAssignable* (i.e. PIMPL with unique_ptr within). Then I have two consumers:

```
 bool consumer1(Object && arg) {
       if(arg ...) { // arg satisfies some condition
          Object b {std::move(arg)};
          // some processing
          return true;
        }
        return false;
 }

 bool consumer2(Object &&arg) {};

 int main() {
     Object arg;
     // some arg initialization here
     if(!consumer1(std::move(arg))) 
        consumer2(std::move(arg));
 }
```

i.e. I want to **move** an instance of Object to consumer1() and if it does not accept it for some reason I move the instance to consumer2().

Alternatively, I could check the state of the instance (i.e. whether it was move from or not) instead of relying of the return value.

While I know [that](https://www.oreilly.com/free/effective-modern-c++.html)

> std::move doesn’t move anything.

I  nevertheless feel uncomfortable due to two moves.

Is it a reasonable approach? Is there a less convoluted way to implement the same idea?

Comment: Conditional moves do make the code harder to follow, but technically they work just fine.

Comment: This strikes me as a very subjective question, and may be off-topic for Stack Overflow. On a personal note, I agree that rvalues that don't actually get moved from are tough to follow the logic. It's even worse if the object being moved has some visible behavior on destruction, because a branch that doesn't actually seat the rvalue reference may result in this destructor being seen at an unexpected time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>This question is rather subjective, but I'll try to answer in the definitive.</sup>

While there isn't anything *technically* incorrect about the code you have authored, since the code will compile and run correctly, from a higher-level this is a design-smell.

Visibly duplicate calls to `std::move` on objects limits a developer's ability to reason about the lifetime of that object, which can diminish readability. Static analysis tools may also flag such a move as a "use-after-move", despite the fact that the object has not actually been seated (which technically, would not be wrong).

A couple cleanup options come to mind, but are entirely optional and would depend on your real use-case:

1. Break out the condition for the `std::move` into a separate check, or
2. Use a fallback pattern

---

### Breaking out the condition

If you can break out `consumer1`'s conditions for consuming `arg`, then you can test this explicitly before you first attempt to consume -- allowing you to have two visibly distinct branches to `std::move(arg)` independently:

```cpp
if(can_consume(arg)) {
    consumer1(std::move(arg));
} else {
    consumer2(std::move(arg));
}
```

---

### Fallback Pattern

An alternative possible refactoring would be to use a fallback pattern, where you design the code such that a dependency-injected "fallback" may occur on failure.

If this is all simply raw functions, a simple example of that could be:

```cpp
using FallbackFunction = void(*)(Object&&);

void consume1_or(Object&& arg, FallbackFunction function)
{
    if(arg ...) { // arg satisfies some condition
        Object b {std::move(arg)};
        // some processing
        return
    }
    // fallback on failure
    (*function)(std::move(arg));
}

...

// use
consume1_or(std::move(arg), &consume2);
```

However, this could also extend to a full interface as well, where something that extends `Consumer` also accepts, on construction, the `Consumer` to pass objects to on failure.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written it, when `1` returns false, then `arg` is still in a valid state so there's nothing wrong with your code (and even if it wasn't, still there would be nothing wrong).